# How can I get a certain key from a json file returned in python?

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble with getting a certain key from a json file in python. I really don't know where to start since I never used json with python before.

```
[
  {
    "author": "Chinua Achebe",
    "country": "Nigeria",
    "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
    "language": "English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
    "pages": 209,
    "title": "Things Fall Apart",
    "year": 1958
  },
  {
    "author": "Hans Christian Andersen",
    "country": "Denmark",
    "imageLink": "images/fairy-tales.jpg",
    "language": "Danish",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tales_Told_for_Children._First_Collection.\n",
    "pages": 784,
    "title": "Fairy tales",
    "year": 1836
  }
]
```

this is a few lines from the json file as an example.

```
import json
f = open('**\\booksset1.json')
data = json.load(f)
```

This part loads the json file, but how would I go ahead to get for example one title from the entire file.

Comment: Your `data` is a list of dicts, akin to what you have in the JSON. You can get the first title like how you would if it were a normal list-of-dicts: `data[0]['title']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [
  {
    "author": "Chinua Achebe",
    "country": "Nigeria",
    "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
    "language": "English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
    "pages": 209,
    "title": "Things Fall Apart",
    "year": 1958
  },
  {
    "author": "Hans Christian Andersen",
    "country": "Denmark",
    "imageLink": "images/fairy-tales.jpg",
    "language": "Danish",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tales_Told_for_Children._First_Collection.\n",
    "pages": 784,
    "title": "Fairy tales",
    "year": 1836
  }
]


# Get all authors in a list (might want to convert to set to remove duplicates)     
authors = [d["author"] for d in data] 
print (authors) 

# Find all books by author 'Chinua Achebe'
for book in data:
    if book['author'] == 'Chinua Achebe':
        print (book)


# Find all books later than year 1950         
for book in data:
    if book['year'] > 1950:
        print (book['title'], book['year'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for loop to access the keys and values.
For example

```
import json
f = open('**\\booksset1.json')
data = json.load(f)

Print First item title: 

print data[0]['title']
To iterate all the of the author details
for d in data:
   print d['author]
   print d['title']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function to get the key's value from the list of dictionary as follows:

```
data = [
  {
    "author": "Chinua Achebe",
    "country": "Nigeria",
    "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
    "language": "English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
    "pages": 209,
    "title": "Things Fall Apart",
    "year": 1958
  },
  {
    "author": "Hans Christian Andersen",
    "country": "Denmark",
    "imageLink": "images/fairy-tales.jpg",
    "language": "Danish",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tales_Told_for_Children._First_Collection.\n",
    "pages": 784,
    "title": "Fairy tales",
    "year": 1836
  }
]

titles = [item.get("title", "") for item in data]
```

Outputting:

```
['Things Fall Apart', 'Fairy tales']
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.load` has converted from text string representation into (in this case) a list of dicts. So to access, say, the `year` of the second one (Fairy tales), use

```
print( data[1]['year'] ) # should output 1836
```

You can do all the usual python things, for example iterate over all the dicts in the list:

```
for d in data:
    author, title, date = d['author'], d['title'], d['year']
    print( f'{author} wrote "{title}" in {year}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble, try using [ReadSettings](https://pypi.org/project/readsettings/).

```
from readsettings import ReadSettings # Import readsettings library
f = ReadSettings("file.json") # Load the JSON file
print(f[0]["author"]) # Print the value of "author" from the first dictionary in the list
```

Here are some other tricks you can do:

```
f[0]["author"] = "Foo Man" # Set the value
f.json() # Get object from the JSON file
```

You can find more information [here](https://readsettings.richie-bendall.ml/).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a basic understanding of how to work with JSON in python.

```
import json
f = open('booksset1.json')
data = json.load(f)
# for single 
print("Aurthor name :",data[0]['author'])
print("Country name :",data[0]['country'])
print()
# for multiple you should use loop
for i in data:
    print(i['title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using this data in a pandas DataFrame, and since your data behaves like a list of dictionaries, you could try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df

                    author  country  ...               title  year
0            Chinua Achebe  Nigeria  ...   Things Fall Apart  1958
1  Hans Christian Andersen  Denmark  ...         Fairy tales  1836
```